# Get number of elements with same class inside a div tag

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to find the number of divs with class name `component ui-draggable dropped` inside a particular div.

Here is the respective HTML code:

```
<div id="tabs-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="drag-drop-box ui-droppable">
    <div class="component ui-draggable dropped">
      <div class="product-view" >
         <a href="#"><span>C</span> us-east-1c</a>
      </div>
    </div><div class="component ui-draggable dropped">
      <div class="product-view">
         <a href="#"><span class="img-product">
         <img alt="" src="img/product_item/1.png"></span> image-11</a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And this is the respective jQuery Code:

```
var getid = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').attr('id');
var clone_nums = $('#'+getid + '> div ').find('.component ui-draggable dropped').length;
alert(clone_nums
```

But alert always pops-up zero. Can anyone guide me what's wrong here? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `$('div[aria-hidden="false"] .component.ui-draggable.dropped')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var getid = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').attr('id');
var clone_nums = $('#'+getid + '> div ').find('.component.ui-draggable.dropped').length;
alert(clone_nums);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9Wp5t/)**

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var clone_nums = $('div[aria-hidden="false"] > div').find('.component.ui-draggable.dropped').length;
alert(clone_nums);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting and really appreciate the fiddle you made for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) like

```
var $div = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]');
var clone_nums = $div.has('.component.ui-draggable.dropped').length;
```

- get all divs with `aria-hidden="false"`
- then filter in only those which is having a descendant with classes `component` `ui-draggable` and `dropped`
- of course you need to execute the script after the target elements are loaded in the dom tree

Comment: I guess the third point you mentioned is causing the issue. Although the target elements are loaded before the execution of the script but still I'm getting zero as alert pop-up. Would you like to take a look at the live url?

Answer (score 1):

```
var clone_nums = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').find('div.component.ui-draggable.dropped').length;


For an element with multiple classes join the name of classes using "."(class selector) between them and don't use spaces.
```